# A question about open subsets of the plane whose components are the interiors of circles.

Tags: general-topology

We assume the Axiom of Choice. Let the term "Bubble Set" denote a proper non-empty open subset of the Euclidean plane P, all of whose components are the interiors of circles-i.e. open disks-which are subsets of P. If B is a Bubble Set, does there always exist a Bubble Set B* such that (1) B* is dense in P and (2) B is a subset of B*? It looks almost intuitively obvious that the answer should be "yes". If B is not already dense in P, then we can always enlarge B by adding another open disc- and this process must end somewhere. But I cannot seem to be able to come up with a proof that really satisfies me.

Comment: I don't see what stops you from saying $\forall p \in P$, let $p$ be the center of an open disk in $B.$

Comment: @DougM, because each connected component must be an open disk and not, say, the union of two slightly overlapping open disks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B$ be given. Let $U=P\setminus \overline B$. Let $\{p_i:i\in\omega\}$ be a dense subset of $U$. Let $D_0$ be an open disk with $p_0\in D_0\subseteq U$. Let $i_1=\min\{i\in\omega:p_i\notin \overline D_0\}$. Let $D_1$ be an open disk with $p_{i_1}\in D_1\subseteq U$ and $D_1\cap D_0=\varnothing$. Continue this process, recursively defining a collection of pairwise disjoint open disks in $U$ such that every $p_i$ is in the closure of some $D_n$.  That is, assuming $i_k$ and $D_k$ have been defined for $k<n$, let $i_n$ be the least integer such that $p_{i_n}$ is not in the closure of any $D_k$, and let $D_n$ be an open disk  with $p_{i_n}\in D_n\subseteq U$ and $D_n\cap D_k=\varnothing$ for $k<n$.

Now let $$B^*=B\cup \bigcup _{n\in\omega} D_n.$$

Then $B^*$ is a bubble set and $B\subseteq B^*$.

$B^*$ is dense in $P$:

(i) $\{p_i:i\in\omega\}\subseteq \bigcup _{n\in\omega} \overline D_n$ implies that $\overline U= \overline{\{p_i:i\in\omega\}}\subseteq  \overline {\bigcup_{n\in\omega}D_n}\subseteq \overline {B^*}$.

(ii) $P\setminus \overline U=B\subseteq B^*$.

Comment: This is just the kind of proof I was looking for-a proof that does not get you bogged down in ordinal numbers, which is what was happening to me. It should be easy to generalize to higher dimensions. It is interesting that if B* is a Bubble Set that is dense in P, the union of the closures of the components of B* is still a proper subset of P.